# Is it possible to use another services linked on Google Home?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I would like to know if it is possible to another linked accounts i.e.: Uber.

So my action is going to trigger some another action: in this case call an uber.

I would like to do the same with Netflix which can directly streaming to a connected device. 
Is it possible to know connected devices (speakers, chromecast, etc)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

During the setup of your Google Home, you can connect other apps (Netflix, Uber, etc.) and devices (Chromecast, Smart TVs, etc.) using the Google Home app.